# Perl: Replace consecutive spaces in this given scenario?

Tags: perl, replace

an excerpt of a big binary file ($data) looks like this:

```
\n1ax943021C               xxx\t2447\t5
\n1ax951605B               yyy\t10400\t6
\n1ax919275  G2L           zzz\t6845\t6
```

The first 25 characters contain an article number, filled with spaces. How can I convert all spaces between the article numbers and the next column into a \x09 ? Note the one or more spaces between different parts of the article number.

I tried a workaround, but that overwrites the article number with ".{25}xxx»"

```
$data =~ s/\n.{25}/\n.{25}xxx/g
```

Anyone able to help?

Thanks so much!

Gary

Comment: what should the output for the given example be?

Comment: Agreed with Nick. It looks like desired output from line 3 should be `"1ax919275G2Lzzz\t6845\t6"` - is that correct? Also, are there any columns (possibly not shown) where you wish to keep spaces?

Comment: The output should be: article_no\x09xyz\x09Second_col\x09Third_col

Whereas the article number can contain several parts of characters delimited by one or more spaces (≤25 characters).

Comment: Easier to read:
1ax919275  G2L<tab>xyz<tab>6845<tab>6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret the question as there being a 25 character wide field that should have its trailing spaces stripped and then delimited by a tab character before the next field. Spaces within the article number should otherwise be preserved (like "1ax919275  G2L").

The following construct should do the trick:

```
$data =~ s/^(.{25})/{$t=$1;$t=~s! *$!\t!;$t}/emg;
```

That matches 25 characters from the beginning of each line in the data, then evaluates an expression for each article number by stripping its trailing spaces and appending a tab character.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, but generates the following error message:

Comment: Global symbol "$t" requires explicit package name at ConvertPData.pl line 55

Comment: Try this instead:

$data =~ s/^(.{25})/{my $t=$1;$t=~s! *$!\t!;$t}/emg;

Comment: It works! Thanks so much!   But I'm lost understanding what the replacement string does, starting from: What is in $1 at the time of execution? I guess that s! makes another replacement for all spaces « *$"? Why all? Why doesn't it find the first spaces in the article number? I don't understand.  But anyway, thanks so much.

Comment: The $1 is a backreference to what was captured within the parenthesis in the search part, i.e. the 25 first characters on the line. Within the expression I assign that to a temporary variable $t so it can be modified. Then I replace zero or more spaces at the end of that string with a tab character. The emg flags do the following: e is for evaluating the right part as an expression, m for treating the source string as multiple lines (^ match at beginning of each line), and g for global replacement (i.e. all lines and not just the first).

Comment: s/ *$/\t/ means to replace zero or more spaces at the end of the string ($) with a tab character. Instead of s// I use s!! to not confuse with the slashes or the outer replacement.

Comment: Thanks again. Now it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) for fixed width data:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1;
print Dumper $_ for map join("\t", unpack("A25A*")), <DATA>;

__DATA__
1ax943021C               xxx    2447    5
1ax951605B               yyy    10400   6
1ax919275  G2L           zzz    6845    6
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = "1ax943021C\txxx\t2447\t5";
$VAR1 = "1ax951605B\tyyy\t10400\t6";
$VAR1 = "1ax919275  G2L\tzzz\t6845\t6";
```

Note that `Data::Dumper`'s `Useqq` option prints whitecharacters in their escaped form.

Basically what I do here is take each line, unpack it, using 2 strings of space padded text (which removes all excess space), join those strings back together with tab and print them. Note also that this preserves the space inside the last string.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

```
$data =~ s/ +/\t/g;
```

Comment: That won't work, because it would treat the first one or more spaces in the article number also as a column separator...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you what - this will match the two columns and print them out - with all the original spaces. Let me know the desired output and I will fix it for you...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict; 

my @file = ('\n1ax943021C               xxx\t2447\t5', '\n1ax951605B               yyy\t10400\t6',
'\n1ax919275  G2L           zzz\t6845\t6');

foreach (@file) {
    my ($match1, $match2) = ($_ =~ /(\\n.{25})(.*)/);
    print "$match1'[insertsomethinghere]'$match2\n";
}
```

Output:

```
\n1ax943021C               '[insertsomethinghere]'xxx\t2447\t5
\n1ax951605B               '[insertsomethinghere]'yyy\t10400\t6
\n1ax919275  G2L           '[insertsomethinghere]'zzz\t6845\t6
```